# Скастить String в WORD

Tags: c++, строки

В файле лежат [Virtual-Key Codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes). Данный хранятся в JSON. Для десериализации JSON использую rapidjson.  
В проекте есть функция:

```
void PressButton(list<WORD> wVkArray)
{
    INPUT ip;
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    for (auto &wVk : wVkArray)
    {
        ip.ki.wVk = wVk;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    }

    for (auto &wVk : wVkArray)
    {
        ip.ki.wVk = wVk;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
}
```

В проекте полученные  Virtual-Key Codes хранятся в String.

Вопрос: как скастить String в WORD для передачи Virtual-Key Codes в параметры функции?

Answer (score 0):

WORD это unsigned short. Поэтому мне необходимо было конвертировать String в unsigned short.

```
unsigned short StringToShort(std::string str)
{
    unsigned short x;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << str;
    ss >> x;
    return x;
}
```